# jquery hide element if href is equal to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently made a jquery code that should hides an element if it's href is equal to another element's but i can't be able to make it work...

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mar1/n2ntvmq1/7/)

HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <a href="1">
        <img scr="a">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
    <a href="1">
        <img scr="a">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="thumb b">
    <a href="2">
        <img scr="b">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:black;}
.thumb{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:green;}
.b{background-color:yellow;}
```

JQUERY

```
var mainhref = $(".a a").attr('href');

if($("a", this).attr('href') == mainhref ) {
    $(".a").hide();
}
else {
    $(".a").show
}
```

Comment: you should probably loop to compare to all.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you expect

Comment: Do you mean hide anchor contain duplicate href?

Comment: @Alexis i expect the div with <class="thumb"> and <href="1">(same as the first div) will hide because it has the same href value

Comment: @MarwaneBettach So only the others should be hide ? and the first should be show ?

Comment: @Alexis nope, if you look at the last div the href value isn't 1 so it should stay visible, only the second div should hide because it has the same href value as the first div

Comment: @MarwaneBettach ok i've understand, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using plain javascript :D

```js
let ar = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    holdarray = [];

Array.from(ar, elem => {
  if(holdarray.includes(elem.getAttribute('href')))
    elem.parentNode.style.display = 'none'
  else
    holdarray.push(elem.getAttribute('href'))
})
```

```css
.a { width:400px;height:100px;background-color:black; }
.thumb { width:400px;height:100px;background-color:green; }
.b { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="a" >
  <a href="1"></a>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
  <a href="1"></a>
</div>

<div class="thumb b">
  <a href="2"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you are using ES6, you can even try `Array.from`

Comment: @Rajesh I'm new to it. Still learning but for now, I'll stick with typescript (angular2). Thanks for information. I will study it :)

Comment: Also a small pointer, only push when `.includes` return false. This will eliminate duplicates

Comment: Just check if it is working as intended. I meant `Array.from(ar).forEach(...)`

Comment: @Rajesh you're right. I missed that. :/ Thanks tho.

Comment: @Rajesh it's working. I just follow the docs given by mdn. I should use this more. :D ES5 and ES6 is too powerful :)

Comment: Yes, even I checked. secongArg is `mapFn`. I missed this initially

Comment: and if for example want to hide only the a tag?

Comment: @MarwaneBettach just remove the (.parentNode).

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for time. I got to go. I will practice my speech for angular2. Hardworking student la. Haha. Learn't a lot from you for 5mins.

Answer (score 2):

Just select by that href (and parent not containing the base div's class 'a') and hide it

```
$('a[href="'+mainhref+'"]').parent(":not(.a)").hide();
```

```js
var mainhref = $(".a a").attr('href');
var parentDiv = $('a[href="'+mainhref+'"]').parent(":not(.a)").hide();
```

```css
.a{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:black;}
.thumb{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:green;}
.b{background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" >
<a href="1">
<img scr="a">
</a>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
<a href="1">
<img scr="a">
</a>
</div>

<div class="thumb b">
<a href="2">
<img scr="b">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The code hide all element has some href but i think question want to hide duplicate href.

Comment: yush as @Mohammad said

Comment: Thanks all, fixed! Is this the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this, only check for thumb class then it will hide specific div which contain same `href`

```
var mainhref = $(".a a").attr('href');

$('.thumb a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('href') == mainhref)
  {
     $(this).parents('.thumb').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with Jquery.

Loop on each `a` and store the href. Select all `<a>` but first with same `href` and hide the parent

```js
$("a").each(function(){
  var href= $(this).attr("href");
  $("a[href='"+href+"']").not(":first").parent().hide();
 });
```

```css
.a{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:black;}
.thumb{width:400px;height:100px;background-color:green;}
.b{background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
    <a href="1">
        <img scr="a">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
    <a href="1">
        <img scr="a">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="thumb b">
    <a href="2">
        <img scr="b">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through all elements.

```
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('href') == mainhref){
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: this is almost what i need... this hides <a> i need it to hide the div above it, i tried by changing "this" with ".thumb" but it hides all the divs with that class

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('href') == mainhref){
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick, using the radio:checked.

```
$($("a").toArray().reverse()).each(function(index, el){
  var href = $(el).attr('href');
  $(el).parent().before('<input type="radio" name="' + href + '" class="hidden" checked />');
})
```

The reason that I use `reverse` is that I want the first `a` tag to remain showing. If you want the last `a` tag to remain, you can just use `$('a')` instead of `$($("a").toArray().reverse())`

css:

```
.hidden { display:none };
input[type=radio]+ div a { display: none };
input[type=radio]:checked + div a { display: block };
```

With this trick, you can make all the `a` tag with a unique `href`. Hope it can help you.